# preloading the next song in a playlist a bit before the current one ends

Tags: javascript, audio, web, web-audio-api

I've made a small media player that works fine but I want to make it so that there's no more loading in between each songs

I know about the preload property but it only preloads the music when the page loads for the first time, so I feel like this wont work

is there a way to do this at all? maybe using the web audio API?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you start playing a song you could watch the `play` event of the audio and already start preloading the next song in the queue.

This is the function I use for preloading audio, you can use it any time, not only in the first time the page being loaded:

```
function preloadAudio (filename) {

    var sound = new Audio();
    sound.preload = 'auto';

    sound.addEventListener('canplaythrough', function () {
        // now the audio is ready to play through
    });

    document.body.appendChild(sound);

    sound.src = filename;
    sound.load();

}
```

Comment: so to do what I want, I'd have to use more than one audio "object"?

Comment: Yes, you need an audio object per sound file you want to play.

Comment: hmm... I don't think I'll be able to add it right now then :/ oh well, thanks for the help though!

Comment: Why aren't you able to do?

Comment: I want to do it using only one audio tag (I'm changing the src when the music finishes right now)