# HTML 5 Audio Tag long buffer time

Tags: html, performance, audio, delay, html5-audio

I am currently using the HTML 5 audio tag in one of my projects. I load an MP3 file from an external source and then initiate it like that:

```
$("#audioPlayer").attr("src",audioStreamURL);
document.getElementById("audioPlayer").play()
```

This works fine, but I noticed that the Audio-Tag takes a long time to buffer before playing the file (Chrome and Safari), which causes a delay of a couple of seconds and thus reduces the user experience significantly.

Checking the console in Chrome, I noticed that the audio most times starts once ca. 5 MB have been "transferred".

I also checked if it is due to the server's latency and loaded the audio file in VLC-Player. However, here it started right away, with no delay at all.

Does anybody know, why Chrome does that? And even more important: Does anybody know a solution for that problem? A workaround or audio-tag alternative?

I would really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 2):

Have a look at the "canplaythrough"-event of HTML5 Audio. This event fires when the Audio is able to play without buffering. You could bind a listener to that event, that will play the Audio.

Maybe this will be faster than just playing the Audio, which will wait for the complete file to be downloaded.

There I demonstrated how to preload an HTML5 Audio: [preloading the next song in a playlist a bit before the current one ends](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29723089/preloading-the-next-song-in-a-playlist-a-bit-before-the-current-one-ends/29724144#29724144)

Comment: Thank you for your quick reply! I have implemented a listener for "canplay", "canplyathrough", "play" and "playing". All of them fire almost simultaneously. I assume that the audio tag has a defined minimum then, do you know how I can change that? Or are there other (maybe jQuery) players that play faster? For example youtube videos also start right away "without" buffering. Unfortunately I am not able to already preload the next file either, because my player always requires a selection by the user.

Comment: I know http://createjs.com/SoundJS, https://github.com/goldfire/howler.js/ and http://jplayer.org/ that generally handle web audio.

Maybe you could take a look too at the `.buffered` attribute of HTML5 audio to decide on your own when it has enough loaded for your taste.

Comment: I already took a small peek at the players you have posted and maybe they will solve this issue. However I still have to test them further. The buffered attribute is a great idea, but unfortunately read only. I could of course check how much has been buffered already by means of JS, but how could I force the audio to start?

Comment: You're absolutely right, it doesn't change anything. I did not think about it to the end yesterday, sorry. During loading of an HTML5 audio/video resource the following events are fired in this order: loadstart, durationchange, loadedmetadata, loadeddata, progress, canplay, canplaythrough... Maybe you could listen to all of them and always console.log audio.buffered and audio.networkState to get an indication why it takes so much time via HTML5 and not via VLC.

Comment: Soo: I did some more digging and I figured out that this delay does not occur when I simply wrap the mp3 inside a m3u file (so only pasting the  url inside a blank file) However I now face three other problems: 1. I need to wrap the mp3 into m3u on the fly. 2. The files keep looping for ever, which is due to the fact that it actually is a playlist format(I guess). 3. Therefore I cannot handle required callbacks for a normal media player. Do you know any possible solutions for those problems? I am doing a lot of research on that topic myself right now, but it seems like my aim is pretty rare.

Comment: PLUS: I would have to stream m4a files and not mp3, however this is my most promising approach so far

Comment: I have no experience with playing m3u files, but it should not be the approach I think, it feels very wrong. Maybe you could post again all relevant code you have, including how you build the audio tag. And maybe an online example...

Comment: Have you ever solved this issue? I am facing it myself now. Audio start fairly quickly in chrome, but when developing for mobile it buffers unneccessarily long (like 5-10 MB are downloaded first).